# Python: Find the first occurance of 1 in a column within a group and repeat the values for subsequent rows in that group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with repeating ID as below

| ID | of_flag | os_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |

I need to create updated column 'of_flag_up' and 'os_flag_up' based on the of_flag and os_flag columns respectively which looks for the first occurance of 1 within each ID group and fill 1 for the rest of the rows as below

| ID | of_flag | os_flag | of_flag_up | os_flag_up |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` "ID" and find the cumulative max for each group using `cummax` and assign them to new columns:

```
df[['of_flag_up','os_flag_up']] = df.groupby('ID')[['of_flag', 'os_flag']].cummax()
```

Output:

```
   ID  of_flag  os_flag  of_flag_up  os_flag_up
0   1        0        1           0           1
1   1        1        0           1           1
2   2        1        0           1           0
3   2        0        1           1           1
4   2        0        0           1           1
```